# Access a variable from a different switch case (from WM_CREATE to WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC in the WinApi)

Tags: c, winapi, switch-statement

I'm trying to change the colour of a label in a WinApi window I'm making.  I take `hwndConnection`, from `CreateWindowW()` in the `WM_CREATE` part of my switch statement, and try to pass it to `hdcConnection()` in the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` part of my statement.

The problem is that `hwndConnection` is uninitialised, since it can't be passed from switch statement to switch statement.  I'm therefore at a loss at how I should send it between the two.

I tried googling the answer.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263831/c-access-variable-from-different-switch-case), which didn't really help me.  The accepted answer suggested moving `CreateWindowW()` out of `WM_CREATE` (which is how I interpreted it anyway), which causes no compiler errors, but instead a frozen screen.  The second uses classes, and some weird syntax I've never seen before (I openly admit I don't know C++).

Here is a stripped down version of my code (I've only included `WndProc` to keep it consise, however I can include the rest if needed)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    HWND hwndConnection;
    HDC hdcConnection;

    switch (msg) {

    case WM_CREATE:

        hwndConnection = CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Not Connected", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT, 260, 0, 100, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)1, NULL, NULL);

        break;

    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: 
        hdcConnection = GetDC(hwndConnection);  // Uninitialised local variable 'hwndConnection' used
        SetBkColor(hdcConnection, RGB(255, 0, 0));
        return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
        break;


    case WM_COMMAND:
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` passes you the HDC to use to make changes. Calling `GetDC` in response to that message is incorrect (and in your code above will result in a GDI resource leak).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is to declare `hwndConnection` static:

```
static HWND hwndConnection(NULL);
```

If you are paranoid, you may want to check in your `case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:` if it was already set. However, I don't see how you can get `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` before `WM_CREATE`...

This code works for me:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
  if ((HWND)lParam == hwndConnection)
  {
    HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam;
    SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
  }
  break;
```

Comment: It compiles without problems, but it doesn't seem to change the colour for some reason.  I'm pretty sure the code should work otherwise

Comment: @Simon - sorry, I assumed that everything else (besides that HWND) works. I don't think you are handling `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` correctly; please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcolorstatic . The handle to the control is passed in `lParam` - check if it is the static control you need; the `HDC` is in `wParam`.

Comment: @Simon - please see the correct handler in my updated answer

Comment: @Simon - now I wonder how another answer (above) fixed your problem?

Comment: I was a little premature if I'm being honest. After seeing this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525669/set-static-text-color-win32 that I found after posting it also used the same function (`GetDlgItem()`), I thought I just needed to modify my code accordingly (I also had the same problem of sending messages between switch statements, so it wasn't actually running either).  It's not until I saw your updated answer, that I actually thought to check the documentation, and I realised it relates to dialog boxes.  Sorry my bad.

Comment: Your answer also explains (which I assume most people who use the WinApi know, I just don't) how you don't run into issues when using the same handles between different switch statements. Since you don't pass hwndConnection, but rather pass lParam and check if that matches the handle for the control in question.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that even if you move `hWndConnection` out of the `switch` so that it is in scope for both `case` branches, it is only initialized in the `WM_CREATE` branch (and `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` is only taken in a completely different call to the window procedure). However, you can use the `GetDlgItem()` function to get the handle of a child window, in this case:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
  hWndConnection = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 1); // 1 is the ID that was assigned as part of the CreateWindow call
  hdc = GetDC(hWndConnection);
  ...
  ReleaseDC(hdc);
  break;
```